# firebase not receiving new entry

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong, my firebase database is not receiving new entry.
here is my function

```
function addBusiness() {

  var database = firebase.database();
  var fname = document.getElementById('first-name').value;
  var lname = document.getElementById('last-name').value;
  var businessname = document.getElementById('business-name').value; 
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  // var Author = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  var logo = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').value;



    var roofRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var businessRef = roofRef.child('Businesses');
    businessRef.push({

           Business: businessname,
           email: email,
           logo: logo, 
    });


  }
```

I have also tried businessRef.push().set{} and still not success. Please help!

Comment: The most likely reason seems that you don't have permission to write the data. Any messages in the JavaScript console? Also see this topic on how to detect such errors: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/24459/detecting-errors-when-writing-a-value-in-javascript#t=201701250605006632661

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use child name in ref as shown below.

```
var roofRef = firebase.database().ref('Businesses');
roofRef.push({
    Business: businessname,
    email: email,
    logo: logo
});
```

Comment: What error are you getting in the console? Also, check if there is any error in your firebase initialization.

Comment: There is no error in your function. Check your function calling.